# How to match the frequency of the characters appear in php

Tags: php

I want to return to automatic e-mail function, I think so: some of the characteristics specified keywords, and then calculate the percentage of keywords in a text appears, if the match, I find the specific message content to reply.
Such as customer e-mail reads: Hello, I want to find this letter, I have not received.
Then my keywords are: letters, did not receive
How I have come to the frequency of these keywords appear in the content of the mail client in

Comment: "letters" and "did not receive" do not occur in your sample mail text ;-)

Comment: haha what a troll :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `substr_count()`

```
<?php
$mail = 'Hello, I want to find this letter, I have not received. Waiting for you to resend the letter.';

$keywords = array(
  'letter',
  'not received'
);

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
  echo "Keyword '$keyword': found " . substr_count($mail, $keyword) . "\n";
}
```

Output

> Keyword 'letter': found 2
>   Keyword 'not received': found 1